# I want to put height constraints on a Flexible widget

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile-development, flutter-widget, flutter-design

My screen has three widgets :

1. First one is a ListView of widgets, the number of widgets can be incremented with a button. I want the ListView to take only the required space that's why I wrapped it in Flexible, but I don't want it to exceed the height of 266. (If it takes more than 266px, it becomes scrollable).
2. Second one is a widget that will take all the remaining space, it's wrapped in Expended.
3. Third one is just a button with defined height.

The code is something like :

```
Scaffold(
  body : Column(
           children:[
               Flexible(child: Widget1()),
               Expanded(child: Widget2()),
               Button(),
          ])
)
```

I tried wrapping the Flexible in a ConstrainedBox and gave it a max height of 266, but the Widget1 took all the 266 height.

In short, I want Widget1 to take the required space, but it can't exceed 266.
Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: tried this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html?

Comment: @pskink shrinkWrap is set to true in the ListView, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @pskink yes I wrapped it in a container with constaints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In listview add the property [shrinkwrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html): true, and wrap the Widget1 with container with BoxConstraints, maxheight: 266.

```
class UpdateListViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const UpdateListViewExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UpdateListViewExample> createState() => _UpdateListViewExampleState();
}

class _UpdateListViewExampleState extends State<UpdateListViewExample> {
  List list = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: 266,
            ),
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Widget1(list: list),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Expanded(child: Widget2()),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            list.add(list.length + 1);
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: const Text("Click Me"),
        ),
      ])),
    );
  }
}

class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Widget1({Key? key, required this.list}) : super(key: key);

  final List list;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: [
        for (var item in list)
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              color: Colors.blue,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                '$item',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Widget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Widget2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. It creates another problem of overflowing.

Comment: Actually the problem was a conflict between the ListView and the SingleChildScrollView that's wrapping the content of Widget1.This is what solved my problem : adding `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` to the ListView.